# Sum columns that do not include duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with SUM function in SQL Server. How to SUM TotalA column but not get duplicate values in Os column?

I am using Group by, distinct but inefficient.

[image: MSSQL Column Images]

Comment: How about you post your query...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
select os, sum(distinct totala)
from table t
group by os;
```

If you want all sum then remove `distinct` :

```
select os, sum(totala)
from table t
group by os;
```

Both query will produce unique `os`s but, first one will return unique sum & second would return all sum.

You can also use sub-query & do aggregation :

```
select os, sum(totala) as totala
from (select distinct os, totala  
      from table t
     ) t
group by os;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(TotalA)
from (select os, max(TotalA) as TotalA
      from t
      group by os
     ) o;
```

Do not even consider `sum(distinct TotalA)`.  I have never used this in a SQL query, because it does nothing useful.  The problem is that two different `os`s could have the same `TotalA` value -- and one of the values would not be included in the `sum()`.

Comment: @HoaAnhĐào . . . This is a *correct* solution.  Yogesh's first solution is not correct, and should not be used, which is why I answered.